# Notion API - Notion database model is also a block?

Tags: database, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, notion-api

https://developers.notion.com/reference/block

> A block object represents content within Notion. Blocks can be text, lists, media, and more. A page is a type of block, too!

As far as i know, everything in Notion is a block, a page is a block has children blocks; so the database is also a block ?

If I create a Notion clone, should I go with the model like:

- users
- workspaces
- blocks (page, text, image, to_do...)
- databases

or like:

- users
- workspaces
- blocks (database, page, text, image, to_do...)

Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to Notion API reference, database, page, block are three different objects. Layer by layer.

> Database objects describe the property schema of a database in Notion. Pages are the items (or children) in a database.

> The Page object contains the property values of a single Notion page. { … } Page content is available as blocks.

Page object does not share the same properties as block object. They shouldn’t be considered as the same model.

Suggested model design should be;

- users
- workspaces
- databases
- pages
- blocks (text, image, to_do...)

Comment: But don't you think there is a distinction between the database items settings, the fields.... and the content it self ? 

Indeed it is always possible to move database item out of a database, so it means that in that case, it will be a simple page and inside this page it has some block. 

and a page is a block too also.....